# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s c++ objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My error is:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:

"security::token::get_imp_aes_key_from_pin(unsigned char*, crypto::aes::key_type&)", referenced from:
      -[MTIPSession remotingSessionRequestDidFinish:received:] in MTIPSession.o

"security::token::deserialize(conversion::der::array const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::vector > const&)", referenced from:
      -[MTIPSession remotingSessionRequestDidFinish:received:] in MTIPSession.o

"security::token::get_imp_3des_key_from_pin(unsigned char*, crypto::des::triple::key_type&)", referenced from:
      (anonymous namespace)::flagIndexFromPIN(unsigned char, unsigned char*) in PINHint.o
      -[MTIPSession remotingSessionRequestDidFinish:received:] in MTIPSession.o

So my question is, am I missing a library or something? I am building the app against iPhone5 which has armv7s architecture. My c++ standard library is: libc++. MTIPSession file is in custom library, which is linked with search path. Please help, Im desperate...

Comment: The issue is very localized to you.  Who knows where the `security` namespace is defined? Or the `token` class within it?  Start by searching for `security` in your project before we can proceed.

Comment: namespace security is in file token.h which is in the library which I mentioned in the question...

Comment: OK, so you have the header file and the static library file?  It's one of two things: 1. you are not linking-in this library.  2. the library was not compiled with the armv7s CPU architecture.

Comment: Yes, I have header file and the static library file. The second one is not, because its a FAT .a file. The first one then. I have the library in $(PROJECT_DIR)/Library folder and I set up the Library search path for my target to: $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Library. And I also have -libraryname in Linker flags...

Comment: I think you'd get a `library not found` error from the linker anyway.  Look closer at the linker build log for clues (add it to your question if you want help from us).

Comment: After all, my lib is not compiled with armv7s, but armv7 and armv64. I have iPhone5 which has armv7s, and simulator in xcode of course, which is i386. Is iPhone5 compatible with armv7 or armv64? Because now I get error: No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv64)............